# In a batch file, how would I compare a returned value to a value that I set and then return a true or false?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I want to compare the first 3 sets or the third set of numbers in %ip% to the home ip.

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping shaws104 -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set ip=%%a)
echo %ip%
set home=192.168.100.xxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3delims=." %%a in ("%ip%") do set "ipn=%%a%%b%%c"
for /f "tokens=1-3delims=." %%a in ("%home%") do set "homen=%%a%%b%%c"
if "%ipn%"=="%homen%" (echo equal) else echo not equal
```

Comment: This works great. How would I set the equal or not equal in a statement? As in: IF equal goto :computer1 IF not equal goto :computer2

Comment: yes, don't forget the brackets around the first `(goto:computer1)`, otherwise it doesn't work :)

Comment: Wonderful! I've been struggling with this for days.